# Moving Slider value based on change in ViewModel in Compose

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, slider

My overall goal is to be able to set the default value of the slider to the value from within the viewModel and allow the user to slide that value. I set up the variable to save the default value like this:

```
val uiState by viewModel.uiState.collectAsState()
var selectedIncome by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf(uiState.medianEarning!!.toFloat()) }
```

From my understanding this creates a variable where the state is saved within the component which is needed for the slider. Then within my slider I try to update this value like this:

```
Text(selectedIncome.toString(),
     modifier = Modifier
                .align(Alignment.CenterHorizontally)
)

Slider(
    value = selectedIncome,
    onValueChange = { selectedIncome = it},
    valueRange = selectedIncome.times(.8f) .. selectedIncome.times(1.2f)
)
```

This sets the value to the default I want, however when I slide, only the text is updated and not the slider.

I tried to do it by changing the value directly in the viewModel and this method set the default value to 0 (default value within the viewModel) and after reading I realized that it won't rerender the `rememberSaveable()` and it is stuck in the default value of 0.

I tried the use a LaunchedEffect to force an update of the UI when `uiState.medianIncome` changes but this still does not update the default of the slider.

Comment: Can you provide ``viewModel.uiState``

Comment: Inside of my view model I have two variable like this     ```private val _uiState = MutableStateFlow(ResultsUiState())
    val uiState = _uiState.asStateFlow()```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is happening because `valueRange` of your `Slider` is dynamically changing together with `selectedIncome` value. You should make it depend on the initial value of `uiState.medianEarning`.

To update `selectedIncome` when `uiState` changes, pass `uiState.medianEarning` as an argument to `rememberSaveable`. This will cause it to rerun the `init` block.

```
val medianEarning = uiState.medianEarning!!.toFloat()
var selectedIncome by rememberSaveable(uiState.medianEarning) { mutableFloatStateOf(medianEarning) }

Slider(
    //...
    valueRange = medianEarning.times(.8f) .. medianEarning.times(1.2f)
)
```

Comment: While that fixes the slider, it still does not set the selectedIncome properly and the value starts as 0 rather than the updated value that is gotten from the viewModel